# Is there a way to have console.log() log messages in IE with the console closed?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have been reading that console.log in IE only works when the console exists (is open).

I am currently working through a timing issue in IE and for whatever reason I can only replicate the issue when the console is closed.  Therefore, using console.log will not help me since I cannot replicate the issue when the console is open.

Is there anyway to have console.log work in IE with the console closed?  Is there another approach I could use to write debug data from the browser?

Comment: Check this page. Show other methods available in console object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the problem only happens when the console is closed, it may be possible that `console.log` itself is failing.

I'll generally put this at the top of my master page or layout page, to guarantee that it runs before anything else:

```
if (!window.console) { window.console = { log: function() { } }; }
```

So if `console` doesn't exist, like in old IE, it won't cause any issues if you call `console.log`. Of course, if you potentially use any of the other `console` functions, define those as well.

You can always assign something real to `log` instead of a dummy call - maybe `log` can execute an AJAX request to a simple handler which logs the message on the server.

Comment: This will help avoid any errors, but the goal seems to be to still see the messages being logged.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Probably right. I suppose I should clarify that a bit. I'll edit.

Comment: So it sounds like there is no way to have console.log put messages in the console unless it is open in IE.  I will try the AJAX suggestion.  I am trying to sort out a timing issue in IE so I am not sure if introducing a AJAX call will work, but I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE9+ you can deattach the debugger console. Then keep open the console but in its own window.

Comment: Also you can add certain console.warn() to certain lines of code to open the debugger. Similarly to console.debug from chrome